# Connecting socket.io client to different hosting

Tags: javascript, websocket, server, socket.io, hosting

So a website of mine is hosted on godaddy, now I want to connect it with a server that is running socket.io, and I have some balance on digitalocean. However, I am not sure how I would do this, I think it should be like this for client side?

```
var socket = io.connect('http://Digital.ocean.ip.here:port');
```

and then server side like this

```
http.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:port');
});
```

the only thing is that if this is how I am supposed to do it (and it even is possible if it's not the localhost), than users will be able to see the ip of my droplet when they take a look in the source code, and perhaps DDOS it or maybe worse I don't know?
When I see other sites using socket.io for a chat for instance, I never see their IP. Does that mean they host their entire website on a service provider where they are able to use socket.io/node.js?
Any answer will be highly appreciated!

--Edit--
My client wouldn't accept http and therefore I decided to buy a domain and ssl so it would use https.

Comment: You always can see the IP of the server you are connecting to because you cannot estabilish a WebSocket connection without sending an HTTP handshake request first, which includes the server's hostname (which in turn can be resolved to an IP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to every hide the IP address of a server that a browser connects to.  It makes no difference whether the connection to the server is http or socket.io or any other TCP based connection.  Anyone can see the IP address.  So, that simply isn't something you can protect or should worry about.

In most cases, code will use a DNS host name (not an IP address), but the DNS service itself provides a way to lookup the IP address for a host name so the IP address can be fetched that way.  Or, one can just load a debugger or local network snooper and easily see what IP address is being connected to.  A host's IP address is simply not a secret.

If you are worried about DDOS, then you will have to implement server-side protection from those types of attacks.  You can't do anything in the client to protect from those kinds of attacks.